# Any conference videos online that you guys can recommend?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef

I like watching conference presentations that show you how to do things when it comes to server setup/deployment etc.

Any good ones out there?

The more practical and hands on the better.

Comment: Community wiki?

Answer (score 3):

check out [CloudifySource TV](http://www.cloudifysource.org/cloudifysourcetv), some videos on how to orchestrate services using Cloudify, an open source PaaS stack for setting and orchestrating application deployment on the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Since you used the "chef" tag, check out http://opscode.blip.tv

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking in youtube for videos, since it looks like you're specially interested in systems management I think that the following conference videos would be ideal for you

- Velocity Conference Videos http://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia
- LISA Conference videos http://www.usenix.org/events/lisa/

Those are the two main sysadmin conferences right now, I would start by looking at those and then you can always proceed to further conferences as your requirements change

Answer (score 0):

http://confreaks.net/events has a lot of videos. But they are more around programming than server maintenance/setup.

http://pivotallabs.com/talks/ has a number of good videos, though they aren't conference videos, they are similar. Again, though, the focus is more on the software development process.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.securitytube.net/, obviously it is mostly about security but there is a lot of stuff on there that is really useful for sysadmin's. I found a great video there about tcpdump and SELinux.